# Python3 prompt user input for a limited time, then enter a default if user doesn't respond

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, timeout

Python3: I'm trying to allow a user a given amount of time to enter a response into an input, but after a given amount of time if they haven't entered anything, I want to abort the input and assign a default value to the variable that is storing the input, or otherwise feed default values into the input statement after the given time period.

I've tried this:

```
from threading import Timer
timeout = 2
t = Timer(timeout, print, ["\nSorry, time is up"])
t.start()
answer = input("You have 2 seconds to answer:")
t.cancel()
print(answer)
```

from a different stack overflow post, but the problem is that the interpreter still prompts the user for input even after the final line is executed and `answer` is printed, and this won't work for what I'm trying to do (essentially, a command line game that needs to keep going when the player isn't giving it input but update when it does receive input).

What is the best way to do this? I know python doesn't really have a timeout function or something like that, but is there any way to achieve this via system commands or a module?

Answer (score 0):

There are several plausible approaches (some of which are probably Unix-specific):

1. Read the input in a `subprocess` that can be `kill`ed after the timeout.  (Many functions, including [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), accept a `timeout` parameter to automate this.)
2. Use `alarm` or similar to send your own process a signal (and install a `signal` handler that throws an exception).
3. Have another thread `close` the descriptor being read after the timeout; this sounds drastic but is generally said to work, so long as you don’t accidentally `open` a file on the closed descriptor before restoring it with `dup2`.
4. Read the input with lower-level facilities like non-blocking `read` and `select`—which will unfortunately disable nice things like `readline`.

In any case, you have to decide what to do with incomplete but non-empty input entered before the timeout.  The terminal driver will likely transfer it invisibly to the next input prompt by default.

Comment: I'm currently developing on Windows, but trying to design the code to be cross-platform to OS X. How would you go about implementing the `subprocess` method you suggested?

Comment: @AndrewMistele: I edited in a trivial pointer to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `select` call may be a easier way.

```
import sys, select

print "You have ten seconds to answer!"

i, o, e = select.select( [sys.stdin], [], [], 10 )

if (i):
  print "You said", sys.stdin.readline().strip()
else:
  print "You said nothing!"
```

Refer to [Keyboard input with timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2904057/6229055)