# How to stop inifinite loop with specific key instead of keyboard Interrupt exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, infinite-loop, pynput

Simplified version of code is below. In the while loop I normally process data from serial port and measurement is not limited by time or any value. I want to stop execution with key anytime i need to stop.

try-except is easiest way but it will affect also main code it is implemented. It is not good option in my case. I couldn't find how to fit keyboard monitoring here [enter link description here](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/)into class and also same for signals. I would like to insert an if-statement which calls other function in class to stop execution of loop. Any help would appreciated. Thanks

```
import time

class Something:

    def __init__(self):
        self.looping()

    def looping(self):
        i=0
        while True:
            i+=1
            time.sleep(1)
            print(i)

some=Something()
```

Comment: Why would a `try` / `except KeyboardInterrupt` affect the rest of your code?

Comment: Old related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python

Comment: You could create a second thread that changes a variable value on keyboardinput. And let the main thread run the while loop while variable True.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        self.looping()

    def looping(self):
        i=0

        while True:
            try:
                i+=1
                time.sleep(1)
                print(i)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break
some=Something()
```

Comment: I did this but instead of this, i would like assign a key for break. not ctrl+c