# How to properly use asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

The problem is that I keep getting `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed` error even when I use `return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED` inside `await asyncio.wait()`.

My code:

```
async def task_manager():
    tasks = [grab_proxy() for _ in range(10)]
    finished, unfinished = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

    for x in finished:
        result = x.result()

        if result:
            return result


def get_proxy_loop():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

    proxy = loop.run_until_complete(task_manager())

    loop.close()
    return proxy


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = get_proxy_loop()

    print(type(p))
    print(p)
```

Expected behaviour:

`return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED` should kill all remaining tasks when first result is returned "under the hood".

But in fact there still remain uncompleted tasks after first result returned. And after I close the loop in `get_proxy_loop()` and access result inside `__main__` those remaing tasks raise `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`.

Console output:

```
<class 'str'>
78.32.35.21:55075
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<grab_proxy() running at /home/pata/PycharmProjects/accs_farm/accs_farm/proxy_grabber.py:187> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fc5187a8798>()]>>
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object grab_proxy at 0x7fc5150aae60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pata/proxy_grabber.py", line 187, in grab_proxy
    proxy = await async_get_proxy()
  File "/home/pata/proxy_grabber.py", line 138, in async_get_proxy
    async with session.get(provider_url, timeout=5, params=params) as r:
  File "/home/pata/venvs/test_celery/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 855, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/pata/venvs/test_celery/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 396, in _request
    conn.close()
  File "/home/pata/venvs/test_celery/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 110, in close
    self._key, self._protocol, should_close=True)
  File "/home/pata/venvs/test_celery/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 547, in _release
Event loop is closed
    transport = protocol.close()
  File "/home/pata/venvs/test_celery/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client_proto.py", line 54, in close
    transport.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 621, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 580, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 366, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
...
...
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<grab_proxy() done, defined at /home/pata/proxy_grabber.py:183> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[BaseSelectorEventLoop._sock_connect_done(11)(), <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fc514d15e28>()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<grab_proxy() done, defined at /proxy_grabber.py:183> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fc5187a8588>()]>>
Event loop is closed
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: *`return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED` should kill all remaining tasks when first result is returned "under the hood".*. Why should it do that? You are asking to gain control again in that coroutine when **one** of the tasks has completed. The other tasks are still active at that point.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so how I should to wait for those remaining tasks are finished before closing the loop?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `asyncio.wait(..., return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)` coroutine returns when *at least one* of the tasks has completed. Other tasks can still be active. It is *not* the job of `asyncio.wait()` to cancel those tasks for you. The use-case of `asyncio.wait(..., return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)` is to let you monitor tasks and act on their results *as they complete*; you usually would call it repeatedly until all your tasks are finished.

From the [`asyncio.wait()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait):

> Run awaitable objects in the *aws* set concurrently and block until the condition specified by *return_when*.
>
> [...]
>
> *return_when* indicates when this function should return. It must be one of the following constants:
>
> `FIRST_COMPLETED`
>   The function will return when any future finishes or is cancelled.
>
> [...]
>
> Unlike `wait_for()`, `wait()` does not cancel the futures when a timeout occurs.

The documentation explicitly states that it will not cancel futures, even when you set a timeout (if you do set a timeout, then the first *done* set is simply empty, the tasks are all still active and listed in the second *pending* set).

If you need the unfinished tasks to be cancelled, do so explicitly:

```
while tasks:
    finished, unfinished = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

    for x in finished:
        result = x.result()

        if result:
            # cancel the other tasks, we have a result. We need to wait for the cancellations
            # to propagate.
            for task in unfinished:
                task.cancel()
            await asyncio.wait(unfinished)
            return result

    tasks = unfinished
```

Demo with some extra printing and randomised tasks:

```
>>> import asyncio
>>> import random
>>> async def grab_proxy(taskid):
...     await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 1))
...     result = random.choice([None, None, None, 'result'])
...     print(f'Task #{taskid} producing result {result!r}')
...     return result
...
>>> async def task_manager():
...     tasks = [grab_proxy(i) for i in range(10)]
...     while tasks:
...         finished, unfinished = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
...         for x in finished:
...             result = x.result()
...             print(f"Finished task produced {result!r}")
...             if result:
...                 # cancel the other tasks, we have a result. We need to wait for the cancellations
...                 # to propagate.
...                 print(f"Cancelling {len(unfinished)} remaining tasks")
...                 for task in unfinished:
...                     task.cancel()
...                 await asyncio.wait(unfinished)
...                 return result
...         tasks = unfinished
...
>>>
>>> def get_proxy_loop():
...     loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
...     proxy = loop.run_until_complete(task_manager())
...     loop.close()
...     return proxy
...
>>> get_proxy_loop()
Task #7 producing result None
Finished task produced None
Task #0 producing result 'result'
Finished task produced 'result'
Cancelling 8 remaining tasks
'result'
```

Comment: Thank you for fast answer) 
Can you please also provide name of `print(f"Cancelling {len(unfinished)} remaining tasks")` string formatting style?)

Comment: @PATAPOsha: That's a [formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm getting stuck in the for with `as_completed` results - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454576/python-concurrent-futures-using-as-completed-with-decorator

Comment: +1 My requirement was to make 3 parallel requests to API and cancel others on first response. Achieved from the answer. Also, I wished to sent 2 parallel requests within each 3 requests, but in this case wait for both responses, for which used asyncio.gather() (For this refer to https://towardsdatascience.com/fast-and-async-in-python-accelerate-your-requests-using-asyncio-62dafca83c33 )

Comment: I get CancelError on a similar issue (aiohttp/Windows10). Would it be because of Windows? Using 3.10. Will ask a separate question if not linked to windows. tx