# How to use Python Concurrent Futures with decorators

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures

I'm using a decorator for the thread pool executor:

```
from functools import wraps
from .bounded_pool_executor import BoundedThreadPoolExecutor

_DEFAULT_POOL = BoundedThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)

def threadpool(f, executor=None):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        return (executor or _DEFAULT_POOL).submit(f, *args, **kwargs)
```

where the `BoundedThreadPoolExecutor` is defined [here](https://github.com/mowshon/bounded_pool_executor)

When I try to use the concurrent futures in a function decorated with `@threadpool` and then waiting all the futures with`as_completed` like

```
def get_results_as_completed(futures):
    # finished, pending = wait(futures, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)
    futures_results = as_completed(futures)
    for f in futures_results:
        try:
            yield f.result()
        except:
            pass
```

for some worker defined like

```
from thread_support import threadpool
from time import sleep
from random import randint

@threadpool
def my_worker:
     res = {}
     # do something
     sleep(randint(1, 5))
     return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
   futures_results = get_results_as_completed(futures)
       for r in futures_results:
           results.append(r)
```

I cannot get the futures completed despite of the `.result()` call, thus resulting in a infinite loop on futures_results. Why?

Comment: Where are you creating the futures? I don’t see any code filling the `futures` object you pass to `get_results_as_completed()`. I note that calls to `BoundedTreadPool.submit()` also *block* until the pool has a worker available, so by the time that a series of `my _worker` calls would complete there are *at most* 5 futures still incomplete. E.g. if you created 10 in a listcompehension then you’d have to wait 5x 1-5 seconds of sleep time before the list is produced.

Comment: And your `get_results_as_completed()` will only ever complete once all futures in the input sequence are done, if you call it in a loop with the same sequence of futures you’d get the same results back, instantly. Try removing the blanket `except` or at the very least *log the exception thrown* to see if any of these have failed somehow.

Comment: For now this isn’t compete enough to reproduce your issue, sorry. Note that there are two syntax errors in your last sample; `def my_worker:` is missing a parameter definition (if empty, use `()`) and the `for` loop in the `__main__` guard should not be indented further than the line before it.

Comment: I just noticed: your `threadpool` decorator doesn't return the wrapper, so `my_worker` would be set to `None` instead. Presumably your real code has a `return wrap` line you dropped from your posted code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you it works now. Did not get why it should be off topics. Can you tell me please?

Comment: The close banner tells you, as does my earlier comment. We can’t reproduce your problem because we don’t have sufficient information.

Comment: @MartijnPieters updated to be more clear.

Comment: Your code in the question still doesn't run, however. We can't reproduce your problem without a proper [mcve].