# Python multihreading: Return result of fastest thread

Tags: python, multithreading

What is the easiest way to start both threads and return the output of the thread that completes first? I want to ignore the long-running thread and continue executing the rest of the script. In this example, the total time taken should be 1 second and the output should be 1.

```
import threading, time

def one():
    time.sleep(1)
    return 1

def two():
    time.sleep(5)
    return 2

thread_one = threading.Thread(target=one)
thread_two = threading.Thread(target=two)

thread_one.start()
thread_two.start()

print(one())
```

I have looked at using a loop and something like`event = threading.Event()` and `if not event.is_set()`but don't think that I can do that because I am making an API request in one of these threads (not shown for simplicity). Threads are confusing, help appreciated.

EDIT: I think maybe what I want is some sort of conditional join statement at the end.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea

Comment: You actually have three threads there.

Comment: Maybe, but I have two systems in place that do the same thing and take an unpredicatable time, I want the fastest one. I hear that killing threads is a bad idea, but in my case, I can have the slower one running in the background and it won't affect the rest of my script.

Comment: What are your threads supposed to do? Is it I/O?

Comment: Yes, accessing an API

Comment: @NedHulton Maybe using ThreadPool and `.imap_unordered` to get result of first completed thread?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wait until only the first thread is finished in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564804/how-to-wait-until-only-the-first-thread-is-finished-in-python)

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, @NedHulton, but the right tool for your job is asyncio, not multiple threads. For example, httpx's AsyncClient: https://www.python-httpx.org/async/
If you are interested in how to do it with asyncio, let me know.

Comment: @ypnos That is what I want exactly. Thanks very much. If you want, answer with that and I will accept.

Comment: Great! I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is the [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module and in particular the `as_completed` method:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time


def one():
    time.sleep(1)
    return 1


def two():
    time.sleep(5)
    return 2


pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
tasks = [
    pool.submit(one),
    pool.submit(two),
]

first = next(concurrent.futures.as_completed(tasks))

print(first.result())
```

Comment: Sorry, no good, still takes five seconds.

Comment: In fact, it does not. The first result is printed after 1 second. The program waits 5 seconds until it exits, but based on your question that's okay because your actual code will be doing other things.

Comment: Got it, thanks, sorry for missing that.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to do API requests in parallel, the right tool for your job is asyncio, not multiple threads. For example, httpx's AsyncClient: https://www.python-httpx.org/async/

Details on how to start several tasks and get back to work when the first one is finished are laid out in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54787498/21974