# Python does't run some lines of code as it should

Tags: python

can someone help me with this code? It's use is to make timed input for 2 seconds and it needs to print the last line even if the user did or didn't type something in the console (for that time). When I don't type in anything, after printing "Too Slow" it asks me for the same input, so I added IF, but it doesn't really notice it. I hope that someone can help me. Thanks!

```
import time
from threading import Thread
i = 0
answer = None

def check():
    time.sleep(2)
    if answer != None:
        return
    print("Too Slow") #prints this if nothing is typed in (for 2 seconds)
if i == 0:
  i = 1
  Thread(target = check).start()
  answer = input("Input something: ") #program doesn't even notice IF and asks me the second time for input

print("This should be printed instantly after printing Too Slow (when user doesn't input anything)")
```

Comment: _#program doesn't even notice IF and asks me the second time for input_ Which if statement? The one in the function?

Answer (score 0):

The `return` in the `check` function only causes the thread to be completed, but the call to `input` is independent of that thread and thus not interrupted when the `check` function completes. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1336751) for an alternative solution using the [signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) module.

Comment: It still asks me to input something when user doesn't type in anything, but thanks.