# Python force input to stop program from hanging

Tags: python

Imagine I had this:

```
#file main.py

while alive:
    msg = input()
    print(msg)
```

Now in another thread I evaluate either if 'alive' is True or False.
The problem is input() will keep the program hanging.

Is there a way to force it to move on without user interacting with the program?
Or can I just terminate the whole program from inside the other thread?

Comment: Taking input in a thread doesn't kill it or "hang" it. It should still be alive & you should be able to access the `alive` variable from another thread

Comment: the input() function waits for user input and I want to know if there's a way to force it to move on and stop wanting input from user

Comment: The same thread or another thread?

Comment: one thread only evaluates the alive value, main one keeps asking user for input. When alive is set to False i need the main thread to stop asking for that input

Comment: `input()` is a blocking call by default, you an try to interrupt the process with some signal handling. See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout

Comment: Use `asyncio` module to code and handle everything concurrently, despite of being single threaded application

Comment: `async` or `await`, will help you working on other things while waiting for input, but as soon as you provide input, while loop will continue