# How do I add limited input time to my code?

Tags: python

I've been trying to find a good limited-input-time code for Python scripts and I finally got a code to work:

```
from threading import Timer

timeout = 5
t = Timer(timeout, print, ["Time's up!"])
t.start()
entry = input('> ')
t.cancel()
```

but, I need to be able to run a function when the timer ends.
Also - I want the function called inside of the timer code - otherwise if you type your entry before the timer runs out, the function will still be called no matter what.
Could anyone kindly edit this code I have to be able to run a function when the timer ends?

Comment: Hint: `print` is a function, can you replace `print` with something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard input with timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is fine that you block the main thread when the user has not provided any answer, the above code that you have shared might work.

Otherwise you could use `msvcrt` in the following sense:

```
import msvcrt
import time

class TimeoutExpired(Exception):
    pass

def input_with_timeout(prompt, timeout, timer=time.monotonic):
    sys.stdout.write(prompt)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    endtime = timer() + timeout
    result = []
    while timer() < endtime:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            result.append(msvcrt.getwche()) #XXX can it block on multibyte characters?
            if result[-1] == '\n':   #XXX check what Windows returns here
                return ''.join(result[:-1])
        time.sleep(0.04) # just to yield to other processes/threads
    raise TimeoutExpired
```

The above code is compliant with Python3 and you will need to test it.

**Reading from the Python Documentation** https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects

I have come up with the following snippet which might work(Try running in your command line prompt)

```
from threading import Timer


def input_with_timeout(x):    

def time_up():
    answer= None
    print('time up...')

t = Timer(x,time_up) # x is amount of time in seconds
t.start()
try:
    answer = input("enter answer : ")
except Exception:
    print('pass\n')
    answer = None

if answer != True:   # it means if variable has something 
    t.cancel()       # time_up will not execute(so, no skip)

input_with_timeout(5) # try this for five seconds
```