# How to create an input with timeout in Python 3? (Skip input after a specified time period)

Tags: python, input, time, timeout

I'm making any program in **Python 3.7**.

I want to skip `input` function after a specific time.

My code has the structure like the following rough code.

```
def functionA():
    ...(skip)...


def functionB():
    ...(skip)...

#TIMEOUT = 0.5
while True:
    TXT = None
    TXT = input("Enter: ")

    if TXT == None:
        functionA()
    elif 'NAME' in TXT:
        functionB()
    elif TXT == 'EXIT':
        break
    else:
        pass
```

I wanna skip the line `TXT = input("Enter: ")` after `TIMEOUT` time, 0.5 sec. How can I make the code of this flow the way I want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard input with timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `inputimeout` module

You can install the module by running cmd and typing this command

```
pip install inputimeout
```

You can use it like this

```
from inputimeout import inputimeout, TimeoutOccurred
try:
    var = inputimeout(prompt='>>', timeout=5)
except TimeoutOccurred:
    var = ''
```

Steps to use

1. Import the module in file
2. start the try method
3. make a variable and instead of input use `inputimeout` function and enter values a`s prompt=` and `timeout=`
4. In `except TimeoutOccurred:` enter the value of the var if timeout is occured

Answer (score 1):

- Note that timeout of only 0.5 seconds won't give the user enough time to type anything. I would suggest giving more time.

You can use the `inputtimeout` module ([available here](https://pypi.org/project/inputimeout/)):

```
from inputimeout import inputimeout, TimeoutOccurred

def functionA():
    pass


def functionB():
    pass

#TIMEOUT = 0.5
while True:
    TXT = None
    try:
        TXT = inputimeout(prompt = "Enter: ", timeout=0.5)
    except TimeoutOccurred:
        TXT = None

    if TXT == None:
        functionA()
    elif 'NAME' in TXT:
        functionB()
    elif TXT == 'EXIT':
        break
    else:
        pass
```