# Can anyone please explain how does inputimeout() in python work?

Tags: python

I want to take a timed input. If the user doesn't give the input under a limited amount of seconds, the program moves on. So, I learned about inputimeout() but even when I am giving the input within the time limit, it just waits for the timeout. (Also I am not able to solve the problem from other similar questions and that is why I decided to mention this problem)

```py
from inputimeout import inputimeout, TimeoutOccurred
try:
    something = inputimeout(prompt = 'Enter: ', timeout=5)
except TimeoutOccurred:
    print('Time Over')
```

Output for the above code:

```
Enter: e

Time Over

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Even if I give the input within the time limit, it shows Time Over. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python : Skip the input function with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66061767/python-skip-the-input-function-with-timeout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping it simple, it is a module that reads input from the user, but with a twist, it has a timeout placed by the developer, if the program doesn't detect the information from the user, it skips the input.
A simple way to use it would be:

```
timer = 2
var = inputtimeout(prompt='Enter: ', timeout=timer)
```

That would give the user 2 seconds to type, you can also increment with a trycatch block to give a message to the user in case of a timeout.

Comment: Thank you but can you please explain to me why is it skipping the input even after I gave the information?

Comment: Hum... never happened to me, mind sharing the code bit that is having this problem?

Comment: I am getting this problem in the code shared in my question. Then I tried the code you gave too, but even after I gave the input within 2 seconds it shows me timeout error

Comment: Are you pressing Enter after typing "e"?

Comment: yes. But then it waits for the given no. of seconds to be over, then shows Time over

Comment: I just copy and paste the exact same code you posted in your question and it's not showing anything when I type "e" and press Enter before 5 seconds. Try reinstalling `inputtimeout`.

Comment: I tried reinstalling it now. But still the same. Can you please tell me which IDE do you use?

Comment: Ok I tried it in VSC now. IT WORKS!! but for some reason it doesn't work in PyCharm and IDLE