# How to countdown for timer user to input something

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need the countdown to countdown while the user inputs their age

```
# import the time module
import time

# define the countdown func.
def countdown(t):
    
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
    
    print('Fire in the hole!!')


# input time in seconds
t = 10

# function call
countdown(int(t))
```

Comment: What happens when you run this, vs what do you expect? Doesn't look like you ever prompt for input when the timer ends (after the print)

Comment: @OneCricketeer I would like the timer to countdown while the user takes their time to  input something in

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "while the user takes their time", but sounds like you want [a separate thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Comment: @OneCricketeer,as I am fairly new to coding and only was taught simple coding, im afraid i dont understand what the seperate thread is referring to. Basically, the countdown timer runs while waiting for a user input and if the countdown ends, the user does not input something, fire in the hole will be printed out

Comment: In this code, there is no way to prompt for input **and** have counter go down. If you added `input()`, it _stops the execution_ on that line. Therefore, you need a background thread doing the counting while the "main thread" uses an `input()` function

Comment: may i know how i can go about coding with the threading function? like exactly what i need to write? thanks alot for the help, really desperate with the code

Comment: Well, what do you want to happen when the timer stops? If the user has not input something, do you want that do "exit"? Because, I'm not actually sure if that's possible

Comment: Several answers here that seem to do what you're asking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout

Comment: When the timer stops, just have to print ("fire in the hole!!!")

Comment: Sure, but the user "age" prompt would still be present and cannot be stopped without some input, or at least hitting the enter key, I believe

Comment: I think just hitting the enter key, it would be fine, but I really have no idea what other threads regarding to this topic are talking about, i have only gone through a few basic python codes, please help

Comment: I don't know how any answer here would differ from the question I linked above.