# if user doesn't take the action function is omitted

Tags: python, time, stopwatch

Is there any way to give user time to take the action, if he doesn't, program ommits the function? I have written a program with "duration" that you know what I mean.

I want the stopwatch to act like they usually do - I want it to display how time is changing and at the end it should output how many seconds has passed

for example: In that way the stopwatch should behave when we turn it off at 5.34 second:

```
1
2
3
4
5
5.34
```

```
def stopwatch_2():
    start = time.time()
    stop= ''
    print("click something to stop the watch")
    time.sleep(0.9)
    clock_1=0
    clock_2=0
    while(stop==''):
        clock_1=round(time.time()-start,0)
        if (clock_1 > clock_2):
            print(clock_1)
            clock_2=clock_1
```

```
*this moment:*
```

```
        else:
            during(1 sek):
                stop = input()
    print(round(time.time()-start,2))
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout whichs eems to be a diuplicate especially the second answer