# How can you create a timer for an input?

Tags: python

For example:

```
# 5 second response, if user doesn't do it in 5 seconds, then quit() 
a = input('Stack Overflow is cool')

if a == yes
    print('Harold882')
else: 
    print('asdf')
```

### How can you do that, or just make a timer in general?

I also tried making different timers, but they didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard input with timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

answer = None

def check():
    time.sleep(5)
    if answer == None:
        print("Too Slow")
    elif answer == 'yes':
        print('Harold882')
    else:
        print('asdf')
    

Thread(target = check).start()

answer = input("Stack Overflow is cool: ")
```

using the `time` and `threading` modules.