# How to execute the next line code in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to implement a program, which asks for an input, but when it does not receive a response after 3 seconds, the following line of code is executed. For example, an input is declared to receive the "email" input, but if 3 seconds pass and it does not receive any input from the user, the following command line (print) is executed, telling it that it did not detect any input.

```
email = input("Enter your email address: ")
print("To confirm, is your email address:", email)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard input with timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout)

Comment: Also, don't use both version-specific tags `python-3.x` and `python-2.7` simultaneously