# Python get user input password with timeout

Tags: python, terminal, passwords, timeout, getpass

I'm writing a Python application and would like to prompt a user for their password. If they do not enter it within 60 seconds, the program should exit. If they do enter it, their password should be hidden in the terminal.

How do I do this?

**Context**

I've seen posts like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout) that suggest methods to input some user input with a timeout. However, these solutions don't hide input like `getpass` does. I'm wondering if there's some functionality that could use `getpass` or something like it.

Comment: Would something like [this](https://www.codespeedy.com/timeout-a-function-in-python/) help?

Comment: That's an interesting solution, but it seems so low-level. To use threading for something that I feel would be a common use case seems brittle.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call) (which only seems to only work on Unix systems), you can timeout a function call by `signal.alarm()`

```
import getpass
import signal


def timeout(signum, frame):
    print('Timeout!')
    exit()


def get_user_password():
    upass = getpass.getpass()
    return upass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout)
    timeout_in_s = 10

    signal.alarm(timeout_in_s)
    upass = get_user_password()
    signal.alarm(0)  # Stop alarm
```

Comment: That requirement of being a Unix system is what turned me off to that solution in that post. Probably the best option I've seen, though.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit restrictive. But it seems like this or threading is the best way to do it. @whoopscheckmate

Answer (score 1):

It's not a perfect solution, but you could try using multiprocessing:

```
import multiprocessing
import queue


def take_input(q):
    stdin = open(0)
    print("Enter your input: (y/n) >> ", end="", flush=True)
    user_input = stdin.readline()
    q.put(user_input)


def confirm_user_input():
    value = ''
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        q = multiprocessing.Queue()
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=take_input, args=(q,))
        process.start()
        try:
            value = q.get(timeout=10)
        except queue.Empty:
            print("no input...")
        process.terminate()
        process.join()

        if value.strip() == 'y':
            print("confirmed: do something in this case...")
        else:
            print("not confirmed: do something else in that case...")


confirm_user_input()
```

This doesn't use input(), but it waits for response for n seconds and if there's no input, continues with something else and it doesn't require Unix system. Keep in mind it needs to be in **main**. Otherwise you should call it from the main with something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     freeze_support()
     confirm_user_input()
```

In that case remove `if __name__ == "__main__":` from the function.
May be you could implement it in your code.