# Python wait then break

Tags: python

I am trying to wait for user input. If no user input is provided then break. I found this code useful, but the problem is that it will continue if there was no user input provided. Is there something else I can add to make it break instead of continue?

The use case

I am sending a test email to myself. if the test email looks good I will send the email to the targeted people. I have two functions, one for the test and one for the real email. and between them, I need a break in case the test email has a problem.

```
import select
import sys

print('Press enter to continue.', end='', flush=True)
r, w, x = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 600)
print("the code will keep going after 600 seconds pass")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard input with timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout)

Comment: Have you tried `input()`?

Comment: Where do you want to break from ? Will this be inside a loop ?

Comment: I am sending a test email to myself. if the test email looks good I will send the email to the targeted people. I have two functions, one for the test and one for the real email. and between them, I need a break in case the test email has a problem,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your comment (wish is in my opinion way more understandable than the initial question) :

> I am sending a test email to myself. if the test email looks good I will send the email to the targeted people. I have two functions, one for the test and one for the real email. and between them, I need a break in case the test email has a problem

```py
import sys

send_mail_to_me()

answer = input("Send to everybody? Y/n")
if answer == "Y":
    send_mail_to_everybody()
else:
    sys.exit()
```

`sys.exit()` will terminate the Python script. See [this](https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter20_sys.html#:%7E:text=sys.exit()) for detailed information

Answer (score 0):

I would use input

```
input('Press enter to continue.')
```

Comment: That is what I am planning to do if select/sys doesn't provide a way to break the script if the user didn't click on enter

Answer (score 0):

based on python documentation I don't see an option to break after the time out
[https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html][1]

```
select.select(rlist, wlist, xlist[, timeout])
```