# how to force input() to stop and continue the code flow

Tags: python, windows, loops, input, multiprocessing

I need to exit a loop that contains an input statement even if the user hasn't written anything. It receives parameters from a process too, and it must evaluate the content immediately. Something like this:

```py
import multiprocessing

def my_function (my_queue):
    var = ""
    #### some code which finally puts something in the queue ###
    my_queue.put(var)


def main():
    my_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process (target=my_function, args =(my_queue,))
    p1.daemon = True
    p1.start()

    my_var = ""
    
    while (my_queue.empty() is True and my_var == ""):
        my_var = input ("enter a parameter for my_var: ")

    #### code that evaluates the queue and the input as appropiate

## I want to exit the loop if there's something in the queue even if the user hasn't written anything
```

This doesn't work of course. The main loop is stacked in the input part. Any ideas? I'm using Windows. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard input with timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout)

Comment: Hi @Woodford. Thank you but exiting the loop or not doesn't have to do with timeout. I want it to exit the loop when the queue receives something

Comment: I'm sure the author of the comment knows that. Read the answers. The solution to your problem involves signals, just like the answer to that question. Try sending a signal to your main process whenever an element is added to the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer that is presumably cross platform, by abusing the `asyncio` module.

I don't fully understand what I did, and I am sure it is bad form, but I've created two concurrent tasks, one that waits for input, and one that checks the queue for a value and raises an InterruptError. Because of the return_when='FIRST_EXCEPTION' setting, it was necessary for *both* functions to raise an exception. I returned the user input via the exception, since the function never returns.

```
import asyncio
import multiprocessing
import time
from aioconsole import ainput


def my_function(queue):
    time.sleep(3)
    queue.put(5)


async def my_loop(queue):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        if not queue.empty():
            raise InterruptedError

async def my_exceptional_input():
    text = await ainput("Enter input:")
    raise InterruptedError(text)

async def main():
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function, args=(queue,))
    p.start()
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(my_exceptional_input())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(my_loop(queue))
    result = await asyncio.wait([task1, task2], return_when='FIRST_EXCEPTION')
    try:
        task2.result()
    except asyncio.exceptions.InvalidStateError:
        text = str(task1.exception())
    except InterruptedError:
        text = ""
    print('Doing stuff with input %s...' % text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

EDIT: It was silly of me to use 'FIRST_EXCEPTION'. I could have used 'FIRST_COMPLETED' like this:

```
import asyncio
import multiprocessing
import time
from aioconsole import ainput


def my_function(queue):
    time.sleep(3)
    queue.put(5)


async def my_loop(queue):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        if not queue.empty():
            break


async def main():
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function, args=(queue,))
    p.start()
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(ainput("Enter text:"))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(my_loop(queue))
    result = await asyncio.wait([task1, task2], return_when='FIRST_COMPLETED')
    try:
        text = task1.result()
        q = ""
    except asyncio.exceptions.InvalidStateError:
        text = ""
        q = queue.get()
    print('Doing stuff with input %s/%s...' % (text, q))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This really worked for me!! I had to do a bit of research to understand how async works and adapt it to my code, but I could do it and now it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: we send a signal from the child to the parent process using `os.kill`, which raises an exception that we catch in order to escape the `input` function.

```
import multiprocessing
import signal
import time
import os


def my_function (my_queue, pid):
    var = ""
    #### some code which finally puts something in the queue ###
    time.sleep(3)
    my_queue.put(var)
    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGUSR1)


def interrupted(*args):
    print('Item added to queue before user input completed.')
    raise InterruptedError


def main():
    my_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process (target=my_function, args =(my_queue,
                                                             os.getpid()))
#     p1.daemon = True
    p1.start()

    my_var = ""
    try:
        signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, interrupted)
        while (my_queue.empty() is True and my_var == ""):
            my_var = input ("enter a parameter for my_var: ")
    except InterruptedError:
        pass
    print('Processing results...')
    #### code that evaluates the queue and the input as appropiate

## I want to exit the loop if there's something in the queue even if the user hasn't written anything
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code above only works on Unix. I don't know whether the following code will work cross-platform, but it might:

```
import multiprocessing
import signal
import time
import os


def my_function (my_queue, pid):
    var = ""
    #### some code which finally puts something in the queue ###
    time.sleep(3)
    my_queue.put(var)
    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)

def interrupted(*args):
    raise InterruptedError


def main():
    print('I am %s!' % os.getpid())
    my_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process (target=my_function, args =(my_queue,
                                                             os.getpid()))
    p1.daemon = True
    p1.start()

    my_var = ""
    try:
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, interrupted)
        while (my_queue.empty() is True and my_var == ""):
            my_var = input ("enter a parameter for my_var: ")
    except InterruptedError:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if my_queue.empty():
            print('Exiting gracefully...')
            return
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    print('Processing results...')
    time.sleep(10)
    #### code that evaluates the queue and the input as appropiate

## I want to exit the loop if there's something in the queue even if the user hasn't written anything
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Zorgoth. This is the first time I use signal module, so I'm not familiarized with it yet.  It seems SIGUSR1 is not available on Windows... Do you know any alternatives? Thank you in advance

Comment: Try `signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`

Comment: SIGILL does exist in Window but the function interrupted is not accesed when calling     os.kill(pid, signal.SIGILL). Instead, it exists the program without printing the message

Comment: The `signal` documentation lists other signals you could try. Unfortunately, I use MacOS and Linux, so I don't know what works in Windows.

Comment: I am going to try other signals. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: One option might be to use `signal.SIGTERM`, and exit immediately if the queue is empty (i.e., if someone sent SIGTERM in order to kill the program, not because an item was added to the queue). That might work cross-platform.

Comment: I added a solution using SIGTERM that doesn't prevent SIGTERM from doing what it is supposed to do. Let me know if it works, because if it does, it is a cross-platform solution.

Comment: thank you again four your help. The thing is that it doesn't access the function interrupted. I don't know why the program is killed. The handler is not executed

Comment: I think my solution might just not work on Windows then :(

Comment: Actually, one more try: replace SIGTERM with SIGINT or CTRL_C_EVENT. I read that SIGINT throws an InterruptedError on windows, which just so happens to be the same thing we are catching. You might need to replace InterruptedError with KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: Again, the handler is not executed...