# python Keyboard input with timeout? getting error OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: python, select, sys

I am using windows and python 3.8. I want to send additional input into the python script I also want a timeout on the input.

I tried the following:

```
import sys, select

print("You have 5 seconds to answer")

i, o, e = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 5)

if (i):
    print("You said", sys.stdin.readline().strip())
else:
    print("You said nothing")
```

Sources: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout) and [thewebdev](https://thewebdev.info/2021/10/17/how-to-add-keyboard-input-with-timeout-with-python/)

This resulted in an error:

> i, o, e = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 5)

> OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

How would I get timeout for a input working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is:

$ pip install inputimeout

```
from inputimeout import inputimeout, TimeoutOccurred
try:
    something = inputimeout(prompt='>>', timeout=10)
except TimeoutOccurred:
    something = 'Time is up'
print(something)
```