# Is there a possible way to measure key press input in python and return the result in seconds?

Tags: python, variables, input, time

`  # 1 (code introduction)
import random

```
print("Welcome to Response Time Tester!")
print("You will be asked to press Enter after random amounts of time.")
print("How close can you get? ")
print()
while True:
    try:
        rounds = int(input("Enter desired number of rounds: "))
        if rounds <= 0:
            print("Number of rounds must be greater than zero. Try again.")
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input. Enter a number.")

num = random.randint(2, 8)    

for i in range(rounds): 
    print("round 1 of",i+1)
    print(f'Press Enter in', num, 'seconds')

#Difference Rating
#<= 0.25 Excellent!
#<= 0.5 Great!
#<= 1 Good!
#<= 2 OK!
#> 2 Miss
```

so in my code i want to ask the user to press Enter in a certain amount of seconds and that data gets     recorded and put in a variable or something for the result. I will then compile all the results and tell     the user how quick he was based on this scale.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of ways to do this in python, but here is what i would do.

To detect the enter key being press the most standard way would be to install and use the python [keyboard module](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/). Then you can use `keyboard.wait("\n")` which will wait until the user hits the enter key.

For detecting the time your best bet is probably [pref_counter](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/time-perf-counter-function-in-python)  `time.perf_counter()` (needs the time module to be imported `import time`). time.pref_counter() returns the time in seconds, so you can use it to measure the difference in time

here is a start on how you would use both of them

```
for i in range(rounds): 
    print("round 1 of",i+1)
    print(f'Press Enter in', num, 'seconds')
    start_time = time.pref_counter()
    keyboard.wait("\n")
    stop_time = time.pref_counter()
    lapsed_time = stop_time - start_time # time taken to hit enter
```

Comment: are you able to impliment this into my existing code please, because i have no idea how to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the time immediately before starting the go using:

```
import time

...
....
start = time.time()
```

Then read from the keyboard with a timeout of `timeToGuess + 2`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2904057/2836621).

Then measure the elapsed time with:

```
elapsed = time.time() - start
```