# Terminating from loop when the condition is taking input from the user

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop

```
while input("Enter your name"):
   print("hai")
```

This will ask user to enter his name, and wait until he enters something. If the user didn't give any name within 5 seconds,in that case the loop should terminate by itself. how can this possible?

Comment: You could define your own `input` function that overwrites the build in method. Alternatively, depending on where you call the input, you could wrap it in asyncio wait_for with a timeout in an asynchronous function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard input with timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout)