# The Mad Minute - How to get loop to exit when time limit has been reached?

Tags: python

The code runs well...if I complete it but not if I don't. I need the loop to quit when the time limit ends and I haven't finished all questions like a standard test.

```
The Mad Minute
[A] Randomly generate a bunch of different math questions
[B] User cannot continue a question until the correct answer has been made
[C] User have 60 seconds to solve 10 math problems
[D] Add 1 second to the final time for every wrong answer


import random
import time

OPERATORS = ["+", "-", "*"]
MIN_OPERAND = 3
MAX_OPERAND = 9
TOTAL_PROBLEMS = 5

def generateProblem():
    left = random.randint(MIN_OPERAND, MAX_OPERAND)
    right = random.randint(MIN_OPERAND, MAX_OPERAND)
    operator = random.choice(OPERATORS)

    expression = f"{left} {operator} {right}"
    answer = eval(expression)
    return expression, answer

incorrectAnswer = 0
input("Press enter to start!")
print("---------------------")

startTime = time.time()
loop = 0


while time.time() - startTime < 60 and loop < TOTAL_PROBLEMS:
for i in range(TOTAL_PROBLEMS):
        expression, answer = generateProblem()
        while True:
            userInput = input("Problem #" + str(i + 1) + ": " + expression + " = ")
            if userInput == str(answer):
               loop += 1
               break
            incorrectAnswer += 1
print("Time's up!")
# Add any incorrect answer penalization to the total time
endTime = time.time()
totalTime = endTime - startTime
totalTime = "{:.2f}".format(totalTime)

finalTime = float(totalTime) + incorrectAnswer
print("---------------------")

print("You completed The Mad Minute in", totalTime, "seconds with", incorrectAnswer, "incorrect answers! Your final time is", finalTime)
```

I temporarily set it to 5 questions in 5 seconds because answering 30 in 60 just for testing is tedious. I set the timer to 5 also to make sure the loop quits if I just stand around the first question, however it does nothing. I added a loop variable hoping it would hit the condition in the while loop to exit but thing it kicking me out for being to slow to answer questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard input with timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop can go on forever if you are not careful. Remove the first `while` statement and change to the following, which only allows 5 wrong answers for a question, and also checks the time inside the process loop rather than outside it.

```
for i in range(TOTAL_PROBLEMS):
    expression, answer = generateProblem()
    incorrectAnswer = 0 # reset this for each question
    while True:
        userInput = input("Problem #" + str(i + 1) + ": " + expression + " = ")
        if userInput == str(answer):
            break
        incorrectAnswer += 1
        if incorrectAnswer > 5: # avoid infinite loop
            print("Too many failed attempts ...")
            break;
    if time.time() - startTime >= 60: # check the elapsed time here
        print("Time's up!")
        break;
```